# Bash array within itself

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to write code that takes in a .txt file, sorts each line of text into an array, and then makes another array based on each line entry whenever the vertical bar delimiter (|) appears.
I have written code that mostly works, but I am having some issues with the output.

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t myArray < placeholder.txt
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#myArray[@]} ; i++))
do
        #echo "Element [$i]: ${myArray[$i]}"
        declare -a column
        for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#myArray[@]} ; i++))
        do
                 column+=( $(echo $myArray | tr "|" " ") )
        done

        for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#column[@]} ; i++))
        do
                echo "Element [$i]: ${column[$i]}"
        done
done
```

If the input data is:

```
example|of|data|in|array
more|array|data
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Element [0]: example
Element [1]: of
Element [2]: data
Element [3]: in
Element [4]: array
Element [5]: more
Element [6]: array
Element [7]: data
```

But instead I am getting:

```
Element [0]: example
Element [1]: of
Element [2]: data
Element [3]: in
Element [4]: array
Element [5]: example
Element [6]: of
Element [7]: data
Element [8]: in
Element [9]: array
```

I'm almost positive it's an issue with my loops, but let me know if I am going about this the wrong way!

Comment: `echo $myArray` should be `echo "${myArray[$i]}"`

Comment: Why are you doing this in `bash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

First, there's no need for the nested loops. You only have to loop through `myArray` once.

Second, you're not echoing the current element of `myArray`, you're always echoing the first element, because you left out the array index.

Instead of using array indexing you can use `for var in`. And instead of piping to `tr`, set `IFS` to the pipe delimiter.

```
mapfile -t myArray < placeholder.txt
declare -a column
for line in "${myArray[@]}"
do
    IFS='|'
    column+=( $line )
done

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#column[@]} ; i++))
do
    echo "Element [$i]: ${column[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! This mostly works, but for some reason repeats the output an amount equal to the total amount of entries in "column." Any idea why?

Comment: Did you run it twice in the same shell? You need to clear out `$column` between runs.

Comment: Do `column=()` to empty it

Comment: I am a super newbie so this is probably a dumb question but where in the code do I put it?

Comment: Right after you declare the variable

Comment: You might not need it at all in the real script if it just runs this code once. I thought it might just have come from you testing it interactively. That's what happened to me.

Comment: What if I want the column() array to clear at the end of each line (entry in myArray)? Eventually, I will need to use the entries column array to perform other tasks, and then loop to the next entry in myArray and repeat the same set of tasks.

Comment: Then you should use `column=` instead of `column+=`. The whole point os using `+=` is that it adds to the array instead of replacing it.

Comment: When I try to do this, nothing prints out. Is there something else I need to change? (Thank you for your patience btw).